# Simple calculator not adding | Cant figure out why

Tags: python, calculator

```
first = input("Enter First Number: ")
second = input("Enter Second Number: ")
value = first + second

print(first + "+" + second + "=" + value)
```

I want it to add both numbers and give me the result for example 1+2=3, but it keeps doing 1+2=12 instead. does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: your `input` most probably returns a `string` and `stringa + stringb` results in `stringastringb`. You have to convert your strings to numbers first. As you didn't tell us, what language you are using, I can't tell you how to do that ...

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a language tag.

Comment: @derpirscher ohhhh makes sense! thanks! i was very confused as i tried coding this on my own then checked a youtube video and they did the same thing as i did but it worked for them. The language I'm using is python. Sorry about the stupid question i just started learning 30 mins ago aha

Comment: It may have been an old video; in Python 2, `input` would *evaluate* the string read from standard input, equivalent to `eval(raw_input("..."))`. As this is a security risk, Python 3 dropped the evaluating form and made `input` work like the old `raw_input` (which *always* returns a `str`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first = input("Enter First Number: ")
second = input("Enter Second Number: ")
value = float(first) + float(second)

print(str(first) + "+" + str(second) + "=" + str(value))
```

Comment: Sweet!! thank you so much! If you dont mind me asking why doesnt the code work the way i wrote it? i watched a youtube video and they did it the exact same way as me and it was working normally for them